# How to get jqueryui datepicker to display date in client machine's date format?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, datepicker

In an ASP.NET MVC 5 application, how do I get the client computer's datetime format? To clarify, I am looking to get at the windows time format used in the client machine on the taskbar. [image]

```
    <script>          
            $('.datepick').each(function () {
                $(this).datepicker({
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true,
                    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
                    yearRange: "-90:+00"
                });

            });
    </script>
```

Comment: what client computers datetime format? Im not aware of a custom datetime format for my machine. Are you talking about the formatting of time and date in my toolbar? If so no way server side code would have access to that and i doubt javascript would either.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Please see my updated question for clarification.

Comment: I do not think this is possible. Your MVC code certainly doesnt have access because that is being run on the server. Javascript code might be able too, but for security reasons javascript code is usually blocked from accessing information from the local machine it is on.

Comment: In your controller you could use [Request.UserLanguages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.userlanguages.aspx) to get the users culture, but there is no guarantee that it will be passed, which is why you typically ask the user to provide it (in say your Register method), which you can then pass to the view and assign it in the script (but then the date would not bind unless you send it back in ISO format, or create a custom MoelBinder anyway.